# Need help in finding classification algorithms in Azure Machine Learning Experiment

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Need help in finding classification algorithms which can classify the different scored label based on the combination of multiple input parameter in Azure machine learning experiment.

Ex :  In the below example we are taking the combination of input parameters Lic, Rel, type, country and flag and predicting the matching records and returning the Scored labels and its probabilities.
Here we are having multiple scored label value which will vary based on combination of all five parameter.

We require classification algorithm which identifies the scored label and its probabilities based on different set of input parameters in Azure Machine learning experiments

```
Lic Rel        type country flag    Scored label    Scored Probabilities    
C1  indi       HD   USA     Yes     1               0.477611
C2  indi       HD   USA     Yes     2               0.477611
C3  indi       HD   USA     Yes     3               0.477611
C1  indi       HD   USA     Yes     1               0.477611
C5  indi limi  HD   USA     Yes     4               0.477611    
C6  indi limi  HD   CARIB   Yes     5               0.477611    
C7  indi limi  HD   CARIB   Yes     6               0.477611    
C6  indi limi  HD   CARIB   Yes     5               0.477611
```

Comment: This is a Multi-class classification ML problem. There are many algorithms in AzureML Studio you can just drag & drop & use. First make the input data fields categorical/ numerical before training the model.

Comment: We have already use Multi-Class Classification algorithm but couldn't get solution as expected.any other way to solve this type of issue please let us know

Comment: Can you please upload the whole dataset and problem description. Then can give a try